# Arduino Uno Controlling multiple LEDs with one button for different amounts of time

Tags: while-loop, arduino, interrupt, arduino-uno

Thanks in advance for your help.

### Scenario Overview

In the real world, I am using one button to open two mechanical valves, but one of those valves should close after a period of time that we will hard code into the sketch, and the other valve stays open for as long as the button is pushed. For proof of concept, I am lighting two LEDs as stand-ins for the valves.

### Pseudocode

If Button One is pressed, Valve One should Open, and Valve Two should also Open for 200ms then Close.

### Initial Solution

Within the main loop, I look for the button to be pushed as part of an if statement. When that condition is passed, I used a while loop and timer to keep "valve2" open until the time is up. LEDs work, and all is superficially great. However...

### The Issue

When my partner starts putting the actual mechanicals together, valve2 doesn't open because the while loop is cycling so quickly that the voltage required to initiate the opening of the valve is not high enough.

### My Question

1. Is it possible to isolate (without using delays) the loop & evaluation of the timer condition from the main loop in order to allow full power to be sent to the valve mechanism (or LED in this case)? Or am I overthinking this whole thing (likely the case)?

### The Code

```
const int button1 = 2;      //Pin for switch 1
        const int button2 = 3;      //Pin for switch 2
        const int valve1 = 12;    //Pin for relay 1
        const int valve2 = 13;    //Pin for relay 2

        // variables will change:
        int state1 = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
        int state2 = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

        //THIS IS THE TIME IN MILLISECONDS FOR valve2 WHEN button1 IS DEPRESSED
        int valve2time = 200;

        void setup() {
          //switches
          pinMode(button1,INPUT);       //Set button1 as input
          pinMode(button2, INPUT);     //Set button2 as input
          //relays
          pinMode(valve1, OUTPUT);      //Set valve1 as output
          pinMode(valve2, OUTPUT);      //Set valve2 as output
          Serial.begin(9600);
        }

        void loop(){
          state1 = digitalRead(button1);              //state1 returns the state of button1, up or down.
          state2 = digitalRead(button2);              //state2 returns the state of button2, up or down.
          int duration = switchTime();            //Create variable to capture duration of switch press

          if (state1 == LOW && state2 == LOW){     //if no buttons are pressed
            digitalWrite(valve1,LOW);                //make sure valve1 is off
            digitalWrite(valve2,LOW);                //make sure valve2 is off

          }
          else if (state1 == HIGH && state2 == LOW) { //if JUST button one is pressed    
            digitalWrite(valve1,HIGH);               //turn on valve1

            while (duration <= valve2time){           //as long as the timer is below or = to what we defined up top....
              digitalWrite(valve2,HIGH);             //...Turn on valve2...
              break;                               //...Then stop the while loop...
            }

            digitalWrite(valve2,LOW);                //...and finally turn off valve2

          }
          else if (state2 == HIGH){              //final condition, if button two is pressed
            digitalWrite(valve1,HIGH);               //turn on valve1
            digitalWrite(valve2,HIGH);               //turn on valve2
          }

        }


        //return the time in ms that the switch has been pressed (LOW) 
        long switchTime(){
          //these variables are static
          static unsigned long startTime = 0;   //the time the switch state was first detected
          static boolean state;         //the current state of the switch

          if(digitalRead(button1) != state){    //check to see if the switch has changed state
            state = ! state;                //yes, invert the state
            startTime = millis();           //store the time
          }

          if(state == HIGH){
            return millis() - startTime;    //switch pushed, return time in ms
          }
          else{
            return 0;                   //return 0 if the switch is not pushed (in the HIGH state)
          }

        }
```

### UPDATE: The working Code

```
    //button pins
const int BUTTON1_PIN = 2;
const int BUTTON2_PIN = 3;
    const int VALVE1_PIN = 0; //mml for tiny
    const int VALVE2_PIN = 1; //mml for tiny

// IO Channels - Used to simulate arduino IO
boolean inputChannels[] = {LOW, LOW};   // digital input channels "Button1" and "Button2"
boolean outputChannels[] = {LOW, LOW};  // digital output channels "Valve1" and "Valve2"

// =============================================================================================================
// You can probably ignore everything above this line

// State machine variables
const int STATE_CLOSED = 0;
const int STATE_BUTTON1_PRESSED = 1;
const int STATE_BUTTON1_RELEASED = 2;
const int STATE_BUTTON2_PRESSED = 3;
const int STATE_BUTTON2_RELEASED = 4;
int currentState = 0;
int lastState = 0;

// button debounce time in ms
unsigned long BUTTON_DEBOUNCE = 200;
    unsigned long BUTTON1_PRESSED_VALVE2_FLASH = 350;
    unsigned long BUTTON1_RELEASE_VALVE2_FLASH = 1000;

// state tracking arrays
boolean buttonState[] = {LOW, LOW};
boolean buttonDebounce[] = {LOW, LOW};
unsigned long buttonTimers[] = {0, 0};
unsigned long valveTimers[] = {0, 0};

void setup(){
    pinMode(BUTTON1_PIN, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(BUTTON1_PIN, HIGH); //MML
    pinMode(BUTTON2_PIN, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(BUTTON2_PIN, HIGH); //MML
    pinMode(VALVE1_PIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(VALVE2_PIN, OUTPUT);
}
/**
 * Main control loop
 */
void loop() {

    switch (currentState) {

    case STATE_CLOSED:
        handleClosedState();
        lastState = STATE_CLOSED;
        break;

    case STATE_BUTTON1_PRESSED:
        handleButton1PressedState();
        lastState = STATE_BUTTON1_PRESSED;
        break;

    case STATE_BUTTON1_RELEASED:
        handleButton1ReleasedState();
        lastState = STATE_BUTTON1_RELEASED;
        break;

    case STATE_BUTTON2_PRESSED:
        handleButton2PressedState();
        lastState = STATE_BUTTON2_PRESSED;
        break;

    case STATE_BUTTON2_RELEASED:
        handleButton2ReleasedState();
        lastState = STATE_BUTTON2_RELEASED;
        break;

    default:;
    }
}

/**
 * Handler method for STATE_CLOSED
 */
void handleClosedState() {

    // ensure valves are closed
    if (digitalRead(VALVE1_PIN) == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(VALVE1_PIN, LOW);
    }
    if (digitalRead(VALVE1_PIN) == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(VALVE2_PIN, LOW);
    }

    // wait for button1 press
    if (LOW == debouncedDigitalRead(BUTTON1_PIN, BUTTON_DEBOUNCE)) {
        buttonState[BUTTON1_PIN] = LOW;
        currentState = STATE_BUTTON1_PRESSED;
    }
}

/**
 * Handler method for STATE_BUTTON1_PRESSED
 */
void handleButton1PressedState() {

    // check for button1 release
    if (HIGH == debouncedDigitalRead(BUTTON1_PIN, BUTTON_DEBOUNCE)) {
        currentState = STATE_BUTTON1_RELEASED;
        return;
    }

    // open valve1
    if (digitalRead(VALVE1_PIN) == LOW) {
        valveTimers[VALVE1_PIN] = millis();
        digitalWrite(VALVE1_PIN, HIGH);
    }

    // on state change open valve2
    if (lastState != currentState) {
        valveTimers[VALVE2_PIN] = millis();
        digitalWrite(VALVE2_PIN, HIGH);
    }
    // and close it after 200 ms
    else if ((millis() - valveTimers[VALVE2_PIN]) > BUTTON1_PRESSED_VALVE2_FLASH && digitalRead(VALVE2_PIN) == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(VALVE2_PIN, LOW);
    }

    // check for button2 press
    if (LOW == debouncedDigitalRead(BUTTON2_PIN, BUTTON_DEBOUNCE)) {
        currentState = STATE_BUTTON2_PRESSED;
    }
}

/**
 * Handler method for STATE_BUTTON1_RELEASED
 */
void handleButton1ReleasedState() {
    // open valve2
    if (lastState != currentState) {
        valveTimers[VALVE2_PIN] = millis();
        digitalWrite(VALVE2_PIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(VALVE1_PIN, LOW);
    }
    // and close valve2 after 1000ms
    else if ((millis() - valveTimers[VALVE2_PIN] > BUTTON1_RELEASE_VALVE2_FLASH)) {
        digitalWrite(VALVE2_PIN, LOW);
        currentState = STATE_CLOSED;
    }
}

/**
 * Handler method for STATE_BUTTON2_PRESSED
 */
void handleButton2PressedState() {

    // open valve2
    if (digitalRead(VALVE2_PIN) == LOW){
        digitalWrite(VALVE2_PIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(VALVE1_PIN, HIGH);
    }

    // check for button1 release
    if (HIGH == debouncedDigitalRead(BUTTON1_PIN, BUTTON_DEBOUNCE)) {
        currentState = STATE_BUTTON1_RELEASED;
    }
    // check for button2 release
    else if (HIGH == debouncedDigitalRead(BUTTON2_PIN, BUTTON_DEBOUNCE)) {
        currentState = STATE_BUTTON2_RELEASED;
    }
}

/**
* Handler method for STATE_BUTTON2_PRESSED
*/
void handleButton2ReleasedState() {

    // open valve2
    if (digitalRead(VALVE2_PIN) == HIGH){
        digitalWrite(VALVE2_PIN, LOW);
        digitalWrite(VALVE1_PIN, HIGH);
    }

    // check for button1 release
    if (HIGH == debouncedDigitalRead(BUTTON1_PIN, BUTTON_DEBOUNCE)) {
        currentState = STATE_BUTTON1_RELEASED;
    }
    // check for button2 press
    else if (LOW == debouncedDigitalRead(BUTTON2_PIN, BUTTON_DEBOUNCE)) {
        currentState = STATE_BUTTON2_PRESSED;
    }
}

/**
 * Utility for debouncing input channels
 * @param channel
 * @param debounce
 * @return
 */
boolean debouncedDigitalRead(int channel, unsigned long debounce) {
    int input = digitalRead(channel);
    if (input != buttonState[channel] && HIGH == buttonDebounce[channel]) {
        buttonTimers[channel] = millis();
        buttonDebounce[channel] = LOW;
    }
    if ((millis() - buttonTimers[channel]) > debounce) {
        buttonState[channel] = input;
        buttonDebounce[channel] = HIGH;
    }
    return buttonState[channel];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the code to simultaneously a) keep looping to check the buttons, and b) achieve the desired behavior for valve2, you need a software state machine that keeps track of what valve2 is doing.  In the code below, I renamed your state1 and state2 variables, so that I could introduce a new `state` variable that controls valve2.

The `state` variable is normally in the `idle` state.

When button1 is pressed

- valve2 is turned on
- a timestamp is taken
- the `state` is changed to `active`

After a 200 msec delay

- valve2 is turned off
- the `state` is changed to `done`

The `state` will stay `done` until either button1 is released or button2 is pressed, since either of those actions resets the `state` to `idle`.

Here's what the code looks like

```
void loop()
{
    int state = 0;          //variable to keep track of valve2: 0=idle 1=active 2=done
    unsigned long start;    //variable to keep track of when valve2 was turned on

    boolean pressed1 = (digitalRead(button1) == HIGH);    //pressed1 is true if button1 is pressed
    boolean pressed2 = (digitalRead(button2) == HIGH);    //pressed2 is true if button2 is pressed

    if ( !pressed1 && !pressed2 )       //if no buttons are pressed
    {
        digitalWrite(valve1,LOW);               //make sure valve1 is off
        digitalWrite(valve2,LOW);               //make sure valve2 is off
        state = 0;                              //clear valve2 state
    }
    else if ( pressed2 )                //if button2 is pressed
    {
        digitalWrite(valve1,HIGH);              //turn on valve1
        digitalWrite(valve2,HIGH);              //turn on valve2
        state = 0;                              //clear valve2 state
    }
    else                                //button1 is pressed
    {
        digitalWrite(valve1,HIGH);              //turn on valve1

        if ( state == 0 )                   //if valve2 is idle
        {
            digitalWrite(valve2,HIGH);          //turn on valve2
            state = 1;                          //valve2 is active
            start = millis();                   //capture the start time
        }
        else if ( state == 1 )              //if valve2 is active
        {
            if ( millis() - start > 200 )       //has it been 200ms?
            {
                digitalWrite(valve2,LOW);       //turn valve2 is off
                state = 2;                      //valve2 is done
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user3386109, while the logic makes sense, when actually testing the code `valve2` stays on infinitely. When I test `state`, they just constantly bat back and forth between `0` and `1`, never completing and firing `state = 2`.

Comment: @billmix Unfortunately, I don't have an arduino to test on, so I can only guess. One thing to look at is whether the `if (millis() - start > 200)` statement actually works the way it should. You could create a simple test program where `setup()` takes a timestamp `start = millis()` and then `loop()` just repeatedly prints the value of `millis() - start`. That should give an incrementing number that increases at the rate of 1000 per second.

Comment: Or we could blame the hardware and say that [switch bounce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce) is the problem. Or that switch1 is unreliable, so that even when you keep it pressed, it doesn't always return HIGH.

Comment: You were absolutely correct about this. I had a friend help me rewrite as a state machine, and we got it working correctly. Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: @billmix Aha, so the switches were bouncing. Glad that you were able to get it working :)

Comment: Yes -- The switches were bouncing, and my grasp of a state machine has made a lot of things clearer.